# AMD radeon R7 250 Ubuntu 13.10 Open Source Driver

Tags: drivers, 13.10, graphics, radeon

I am using an AMD Radeon R7 250 and I have installed the proprietary drivers from AMD but I would like to try out the Open source driver since I have them on my laptop and that I have good performances. The issue here is that when I uninstall my AMD drivers to get the open source one I am getting some display issues.

My screen get divided in a bunch of tiny blocks that represent my desktop.

So what can I do?

Comment: Have you removed your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file after removing your proprietary drivers? I had a lot of problem with that issue...

Comment: Yes I did and I have reinstalled the open source driver after to make sure they were the one to be used on next reboot

Answer (score -2):

The command-line console is your friend. From your X session, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (it should also work with <kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> or so). That will take you to one of the built in consoles (aka terminals), where you can do the uninstall/reinstall "by hand" using apt-get or whatever.

If you have access to another computer, you could SSH in instead, I think that is set to run on a default Ubuntu install.